# Is there a global object in Python and in Perl as there is in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, perl

In Ruby, when we simply define a method:

```
def test
  puts "test!"
end
```

It becomes a method on a global object (there are no stand-alone functions), and we can even do:

```
puts self
```

Or

```
puts methods.sort
```

Because the global environment is an object itself...

Is this valid to Python and/or Perl? If not, can it be simulated?

## Edit

I'm a compiler enthusiast.

I'm actually trying to implement a compiler for those three languages which use a namespaced version of the Objective-C runtime. I'm trying to figure out how I could access methods/classes/objects defined in one language on another. The class hierarchies should be totally different, but it would be really useful if globally defined methods (like I showed in Ruby) could be directly accessed from one another, transparently, so that's why I'm trying to figure out how Perl and Python treat such things in comparison with Ruby. I'd appreciate suggestions for the problem as well.

Though this question should be relevant to other people as well, I believe/hope. :)

Comment: Didn't think this was worth a full-blown answer, but in perl there are a number of [default variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: In Python, everything can be thought of as a dictionary. An object, for example, has a dictionary mapping attributes to values (other objects) and/or methods (function objects). Of course, there is also the global dictionary (accessible via the built-in method `globals()`.

Comment: Actually, it becomes a `private` instance method of `Object`, not a singleton method of the `main` object.

Comment: @JörgWMittag you sure? :O

Comment: Re your edit: See Inline::* in Perl

Comment: Yes: `Object.private_instance_methods.include?(:test) # => true`. If it *weren't* a method on `Object`, you wouldn't be able to call it "globally", after all. E.g. in `class Foo; def foo; test end end; Foo.new.foo # test!` you would get a `NoMethodError` if `test` were a singleton method of `main`, because `self` is not `main`, it's `Foo.new`. It only works because `Foo.new` is an instance of `Foo`, which is a subclass of `Object` which has the `test` method. (Although it would be a *really* good idea to use a different method name, because there already *is* a "global" `test` in `Kernel`.)

Answer (score 3):

In perl, things will be stored in the symbol table for the containing package (and all packages other than main are themselves contained in main's symbol table).

%main:: is the main package table.  The values in package tables are usually globs, but sometimes other things (e.g. prototypes for forward declarations).

Update: I see you describe your actual goal in the question now.  It looks to me like you want to read [perlcall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html).  Unless you want to actually translate and compile the perl code in Objective C (a very difficult project), in which case you probably want to start with a modified version of [PPI::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PPI/lib/PPI/Dumper.pm) to handle the parsing for you.

Comment: How can I access one package table?

Comment: I'm used to it, I work with commercial compilers. Gonna translate directly to assembler with `liobjc`'s runtime as an experiment. That perlcall really should be useful; thanks a lot! And yeah, I'm a bit crazy, but that happens.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, the `UNIVERSAL` class is base to all other classes.

```
sub UNIVERSAL::method { ... }

$obj->method()     # Works regardless of the object's class
$class->method()   # Works regardless of the class name
```

This is normally something you'd want to avoid.

If you were using the Moose object system, you'd place the method in the a role you'd assign to the classes which should have the method.

Comment: from what I've heard, it's something that Ruby embraces, despite being so very wrong

Comment: Not exactly what I asked. The `main` object in Ruby is not a base class, just a class which represents the runtime (the file itself).

Comment: @ysht `def boo; puts "boo" end` is a method on Object (comparable to UNIVERSAL I guess), but it is _private_, which means it can not be called from a class or an instance. It can not have an explicit  receiver (anything before the dot, or -Perl analogy- the arrow).

Answer (score 2):

Perl is not a pure object oriented language like Ruby. So not everything is an object, and functions are not necessarily methods.

In Perl, it makes more sense to talk about packages (which are roughly equivalent to namespaces). There are no globals in Perl 5; everything belongs in a package. If you don't say otherwise, it goes in a package called `main`.

Comment: Can I get every object and method defined on the `main` package as I would do in Ruby?

Comment: Sure that's what happens by default.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it's the built-in function `globals()`, which returns a dictionary of all globally defined objects. Don't know about Perl though.

To get a list of all globally defined classes, you could use type checking:

```
import inspect
def test(): pass
class test2: pass
print filter(lambda x: inspect.isclass(x[1]), globals().items())
```

Comment: Can I get a list of classes too?

Answer (score 1):

```
def teas():
    return "hello"


print locals() # or globals()
# prints
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'teas': <function teas at 0xb72b4ae4>, '__file__': '/home/user/test.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python there are global and local variables as well. 
For example:

```
def say_hey_2():   
    global hey
    hey= 'hey!'
    print hey, hey
```

Will print both the global hey and local hey.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def test():
...     print 'test!'
... 
>>> print test
<function test at 0x279ec80>
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'test': <function test at 0x279ec80>, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> print globals()['test']
<function test at 0x279ec80>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python when you define a "global", what you're actually defining is an attribute of whatever module you're currently in (which is the `__main__` module, if the code is in the "top-level" script being executed).

So there is no program-wide global environment, and despite the name `globals()` returns a different object in different files.

You can access modules via `sys.modules`, but this collection isn't *necessarily* complete. If you `reload` a module then the old version will stick around if it's referenced from anywhere else, along with any functions defined in it. But it is no longer in `sys.modules`.